# How can I combine duplicates of 1 column, then have multiple results in the same row of another column?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, kql, azure-data-explorer

I am very new to kql, and i am stuck on this query.  I am looking to have query display which users have had sign-ins from different states.  I created this query, but i do not know how to count the results in the column "names".

```
SigninLogs
| project tostring(LocationDetails.state), UserDisplayName
| extend p =pack( 'Locations', LocationDetails_state)
| summarize names = make_set(p)  by UserDisplayName
```

This generates a column "names" with a row like so:

```
[{"Locations":"Arkansas"},{"Locations":"Iowa"},{"Locations":""}]
```

Here is a simple query that grabs all sign-ins from users and another column with the locations.

```
SigninLogs
| where ResultType == "0"
| summarize by UserDisplayName, tostring(LocationDetails.state)
```

Is there a way to combine the duplicates of users column, and then display each location in the second?  If so, could i count each location in order to filter by where location is > 1?

Answer (score 0):

> *I am looking to have query display which users have had sign-ins from different states*

Assuming I understood your question correctly, this could work (using `array_length()`):

```
SigninLogs
| project State = tostring(LocationDetails.state), UserDisplayName
| summarize States = make_set(State) by UserDisplayName
| where array_length(States) > 1 // filter users who had sign-ins from *more than 1 state*
```

Comment: Thank you! this works, i felt like i tried this but i guess not